# I can't get call options such as Viber or Skype

Tags: settings, skype, default-applications, viber-messenger

I've chosen 'direct call' as my default calling option by accident. When I'm calling someone I want to be asked which application I want to choose (Dialer/Viber/Skype). When I go to `settings/applications/manage applications/ALL/dialer storage` (because Dialer is my default option for calling) I can't pick 'clear defaults'; it says that there is no default set. But I'm sure there is!

How can I fix this so that I'm prompted when I want to make a call?

Comment: Which phone / version of Android are you running?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give [Default App Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appiator.defaultappmanager) a try:

> Default App Manager is a simple yet very functional app to manage (set defaults, clear/reset defaults) default applications for different types of actions that Android does. Unlike other applications that allow you to manage defaults for only one-two types of categories, this app allows to you to manage for almost all the common actions.